# Is it possible to use batch_create_entities() to upload KIND_MAP entities?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I trying to batch create entities (KIND_MAP) but this [reference](https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/blob/master/dialogflow_v2/gapic/entity_types_client.py) implies from this line under batch_create_entities():

```
entities = []
```

we can only batch update entities of KIND_LIST and not KIND_MAP.

Is there any work arounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to batch update for entity types who's 'Kind' is 'KIND_MAP'.

Reference: [DialogFlow Issue #100](https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/issues/100)